# Displaying the SP Doc version in a Word Doc

Tags: office-integration

Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

I used to do it in SP2007 by defining a policy & enabling labels, but wondered if there was a better way to do this in 2010?

Answer (score 1):

You could write an Add-in for word that displays the active version within an Word doc...

Comment: How can I access the SP version number from within Word?